# Including XPCOM inFirefox extension

Tags: xul, firefox-addon, xpcom

I have a very limited experience with Firefox extensions development (read [XUL School](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School), written a couple of very simple extensions).

I now need some functionality that is not available through Firefox XPCOM objects, namely running an external process and reading its stdout. It seems that this can be done using [Protozilla](http://protozilla.mozdev.org/index.html). So my problems becomes now to include this external XPCOM object in my XPI so that it will be available to my extension.

I should make clear that my problem is NOT how to build an XPCOM object, since I already have their builds and if I need to change something I already have their makefiles. My problem is: what do I do now? My extensions tree look like

> /
>   -->chrome/
>   -->-->content
>   -->-->-->browserOverlay.js
>   -->-->-->...
>   -->-->locale
>   -->-->-->en-US
>   -->-->-->-->browserOverlay.dtd
>   -->-->-->-->browserOverlay.properties
>   -->-->-->...
>   -->-->skin
>   -->-->-->...
>   -->defaults/
>   -->-->preferences/
>   -->-->-->my_extension.js
>   -->modules/
>   -->-->common.js
>   -->chrome.manifest
>   -->install.rdf

Where should I include the XPCOM files? Do I need to do something to tell Firefox that a new XPCOM object is available?

Comment: For that I'd need to have questions which are answered...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Mozilla developer center,

> **XPCOM Components**
>
> Firefox supports XPCOM components in
>   extensions. You can create your own
>   components easily in JavaScript or in
>   C++ (using the Gecko SDK).
>
> Place all of your .js or .dll files in
>   the `components/` directory - they are
>   automatically registered the first
>   time Firefox runs after your extension
>   is installed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/building_an_extension

Answer (score 0):

You could use [nsIProcess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Running_applications) to launch the process, have it write to a known location, and then read from that file using [nsIFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I//O).

Comment: Yes, I have thought about it. But since I have to do this thousand of times (or tens of thousands) I'd like to avoid writing to a file if possible.

Comment: Well, that is a little scary.  What are you doing, more specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Protozilla has derived in this: http://mozilla-enigmail.org/ipc/ you can find xulrunner enabled binaries there that should allow you to invoke external processes.

The code has been included into the Mozilla codebase (after 10 years, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68702 and http://hg.mozilla.org/ipccode/), but it's not available in Firefox 4, as far as I can tell.